# Github actions workflows are canceled right away

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a problem with running github actions on branches created automatically from within other action. Config file triggers them on push to branches that start with `feature-`.

Then I have a python script using `PyGithub` and `create_git_ref` for branch creation. Everything works fine if I do it from local terminal, branch is created and actions are triggered properly, things change when the same script is launched from within github action using `GITHUB_TOKEN` as an authorization, then those actions are canceled even before they start, anyone experienced such a problem before? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try using a PAT with a different permission scope instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Indeed, PAT resolves the issue, thanks !

Comment: Great, I'll add the solution as official answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The `GITHUB_TOKEN` has [a specific scope os permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token), and it doesn't have the one(s) you need here.

Instead, you need to use a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and add it as a secret (for example **ACCESS_TOKEN** as you can't use the [GITHUB_ prefix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets)) and call it in your workflow using `${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}`.